# How to get sum of two large numbers which can't be held in any primitive datatype?

Tags: java

How to find sum of two large numbers which can't be held in any primitive datatype??

Comment: A good question and aix has given you a great insight.

Comment: @Frank: I see no connection whatsoever with this question and the link you provided.

Comment: haha sry was well-intentioned

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume by "any datatype" you mean "any primitive datatype".

Depending on the type of your data, you could use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Answer (score 3):

You could perform the calculation manually by storing the 2 numbers as `Strings` (or a `char[]` array) and then iterating through `char`-by-`char` performing the addition.

Comment: Geez, it was just a suggestion :-)

Comment: Also just a suggestion from my side ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

  BigInteger n1 = new BigInteger("123456789012345678901234567890");
  BigInteger n2 = new BigInteger("111122222233334445556666");
  BigInteger result = n1.add(n2);
  System.out.println(result.toString());
```